# How do I manage patched libraries in a project?

Tags: python

#### Context

In my python projects I use code from different libraries. Sometimes I come across a library that does 99% of what I want, and the additional 1% I add myself, "patching" the library.

However, these patches are not stored in the git repository of my project. So when I clone the project somewhere else and install the requirements I need to manually patch the installed libraries again.

#### Example

The [exif_delete](https://github.com/theJollySin/exif_delete) package removes EXIF data from images. This is great.
However, it also removes the orientation tag, meaning that images might be shown in an incorrect orientation (e.g. a portrait image is shown on its side).
This can be solved by rotating the image before removing all EXIF data. For this I've added, on my machine, the following:

- On [line 26 of exif_delete.py](https://github.com/theJollySin/exif_delete/blob/master/exif_delete.py#L26): `from PIL import ImageOps`
- On [line 108 of exif_delete.py](https://github.com/theJollySin/exif_delete/blob/master/exif_delete.py#L108): `original = ImageOps.exif_transpose(original)`

#### Question

How can I carry over the patches I've done in the above example to another machine in a robust way?

Comment: Did you try getting the maintainer to merge your changes? There isn't really a good way of keeping these changes: Either you keep a completly local copy that comes with your library, you pusblish your own package, or your changes get merged.

Comment: I've created a pull request, but felt that might be a bit overkill. Keeping a local copy sounds easy, but then I would miss out on any updates the library gets. I was hoping there was some way of (python) scripting a patch. Something along the way of: load library, replace stringU on line 10 with stringV  and replace stringX on line 20 with string Y, reload library.

Comment: That is a terrible idea: If another library relies on that package, you potentially change the behavior for everyone.

Comment: Isn't that the case when doing a pull request as well? And sure, this is not a good idea for  heavily relied on packages, but a standalone package I use in a single conda/venv environment should not be too much of a risk?

Comment: I'm unclear why you're calling `exif_transpose` from *within* the `exif_delete` module. Why not just call that in your code *before* calling `exif_delete`?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Yes, but then it is a new release. You can also create a keyword argument that only optionally changes the behaviour. But randomly changing the behavior of a third party library sounds like a terrible thing to debug.

Comment: @larsks it's an example, I could just handle it in my own code. However, not all patches are that straightforward. Some do add a keyword argument that optionally change the behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everyone says, it is much better to work with the package maintainer to get things fixed.  However, if you need to get things working sooner, but don't want to modify the package in place, you can always just modify the function from your own code.

Since this is a `__main__` program, you would need a new main entry point.  In this case, something like the following should work (including a check that code has not changed):

```
import exif_delete

def my_new_exif_delete(original_file_path, new_file_path):
    # Whatever you want it to do

import inspect
import hashlib

# Possibly over-the-top check that the original code has not changed
expected = '60cea7e2226b9eb4ab2d6a7f1353110d'  # Update to proper md5sum for exif_delete.exif_delete
found = hashlib.md5(inspect.getsource(exif_delete.exif_delete).encode())
if found != expected:
    raise Exception('code appears to have changed--patching aborted')

# Replace exif_delete with one you prefer
exif_delete.exif_delete = my_new_exif_delete

if __name__ == '__main__':
    exif_delete.main()
```

Remember, you can change just about *anything* in Python at runtime, but don't abuse it or you'll confuse yourself and don't ship anything that is patching like this or you'll make people hate your code.